# App can't be restored from background

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I try to restore my app from background it crashes as a result of irregular sequence of starting of fragments. But in case when app running from the scratch everything is ok. Fragments structure and logs please see below.

I'm currently using regular fragments, but with support fragments situation is the same. API 27.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Stucture of fragments:

```
MainActivity
  - FragmentProfileBase
    - FragmentProfile (child fragment)
```

Set base fragment function:

```
private void setFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @Nullable Bundle bundle){

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

if (fragmentCurrent != null) {
    String classCurrent = fragmentCurrent.getClass().getName();
    String classFragment = fragment.getClass().getName();
    if (classCurrent.equalsIgnoreCase(classFragment)) {
        FragmentBaseAbstract fragmentBaseAbstract = (FragmentBaseAbstract) fragmentCurrent;
        fragmentBaseAbstract.setTabClicked();
        return;
    }
    transaction.hide(fragmentCurrent);
}

if (fragment.isAdded())
    transaction.show(fragment);
else
    transaction.add(R.id.frameContainer, fragment);


transaction.commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

fragmentCurrent = fragment;
}
```

Set child fragment function:

```
public void openFragment(Fragment self, Fragment fragment, boolean removeSelf){

FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (self != null) {
    if (removeSelf)
        transaction.remove(self);
    transaction.addToBackStack(self.getClass().getName());
}

transaction
        .add(getBaseContainer(), fragment)
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);

transaction.commit();
}
```

Log of regular run:

```
D/App: onCreate
D/ActivityMain: onCreate
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreate
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfile: onCreate
D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfile: onCreateOptionsMenu
```

Log of run from background:

```
D/App: onCreate
D/FragmentProfile: onCreate actionBar = null
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreate
D/ActivityMain: onCreate
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreate
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfile: onCreate actionBar = android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar@8f9c1fc
D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreateView
D/FragmentProfile: onCreate actionBar = android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar@8f9c1fc
D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
```

Full log:

```
02-24 21:21:53.875 9592-9592/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-24 21:21:54.815 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
02-24 21:21:54.815 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/MultiDex: Installing application
02-24 21:21:54.815 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
02-24 21:21:54.880 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
02-24 21:21:54.908 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
02-24 21:21:54.925 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-24 21:21:54.931 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-24 21:21:54.952 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
02-24 21:21:54.978 9592-9623/com.homework.personalstuff W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
02-24 21:21:54.989 9592-9623/com.homework.personalstuff I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
02-24 21:21:54.989 9592-9623/com.homework.personalstuff I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
02-24 21:21:55.007 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=20KB
02-24 21:21:55.007 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=20KB
02-24 21:21:55.007 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
02-24 21:21:55.017 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( uH6Bo1NMUOVOIQNiB0pLQswb78l1 ).
02-24 21:21:55.053 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
02-24 21:21:55.139 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
02-24 21:21:55.141 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
02-24 21:21:55.143 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-24 21:21:55.166 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: Collection enabled
02-24 21:21:55.166 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: App package, google app id: com.homework.personalstuff, 1:633452378895:android:e2b301a85dc1fba2
02-24 21:21:55.168 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
02-24 21:21:55.168 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
02-24 21:21:55.168 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.homework.personalstuff
02-24 21:21:55.168 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
02-24 21:21:55.180 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/App: onCreate
02-24 21:21:55.197 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ImageCache: Memory cache created (size = 58982)
02-24 21:21:55.298 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ImageCache: Disk cache initialized
02-24 21:21:55.326 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: UserProfileManager
02-24 21:21:55.335 9592-9631/com.homework.personalstuff D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
02-24 21:21:55.383 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: Connecting to remote service
02-24 21:21:55.405 9592-9627/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
02-24 21:21:55.407 9592-9640/com.homework.personalstuff D/Malevich: ImageWorker: HTTP cache initialized
02-24 21:21:55.456 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=43KB
02-24 21:21:55.457 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=42KB
02-24 21:21:55.457 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
02-24 21:21:55.487 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff V/FA: onActivityCreated
02-24 21:21:55.591 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreate
02-24 21:21:55.622 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreate
02-24 21:21:55.622 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ActivityMain: onCreate
02-24 21:21:55.827 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: checkSignIn
02-24 21:21:55.913 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: checkSignIn prefs facebookIsSignedIn = true
02-24 21:21:55.913 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: checkSignIn firebase getCurrentUser = com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzh@df479cd
02-24 21:21:55.914 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: dbInitials
02-24 21:21:55.914 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: setDbLastVisited
02-24 21:21:55.954 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: subscribeFriends
02-24 21:21:55.956 9592-9664/com.homework.personalstuff I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
02-24 21:21:55.957 9592-9664/com.homework.personalstuff I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
02-24 21:21:55.959 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/UserProfileManager: subscribeProfileChanged
02-24 21:21:55.962 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ActivityMain: checkSignIn = true
02-24 21:21:55.969 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/StuffManager: Create
02-24 21:21:56.018 9592-9664/com.homework.personalstuff W/zygote64: Unsupported class loader
02-24 21:21:56.021 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/StuffManager: updatePresets
02-24 21:21:56.042 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/StuffManager: updatePresets listParams = []
02-24 21:21:56.051 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/SocialManager: Create
02-24 21:21:56.051 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ActivityMain: hasExtra type = null
02-24 21:21:56.051 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/ActivityMain: setFragment
02-24 21:21:56.058 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreateView
02-24 21:21:56.060 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: openFragment removeSelf true
02-24 21:21:56.062 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
02-24 21:21:56.370 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=118KB, data=108KB
02-24 21:21:56.370 9592-9597/com.homework.personalstuff I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=110KB, data=79KB
02-24 21:21:56.377 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreate
02-24 21:21:56.380 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
02-24 21:21:56.449 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreate
02-24 21:21:56.450 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: onCreateView
02-24 21:21:56.452 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: openFragment removeSelf true
02-24 21:21:56.453 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreate
02-24 21:21:56.454 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onCreateView
02-24 21:21:56.520 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfileBase: onStart
02-24 21:21:56.520 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/FragmentProfile: onStart
02-24 21:21:56.521 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-24 21:21:56.525 9592-9592/com.homework.personalstuff E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.homework.personalstuff, PID: 9592
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.homework.personalstuff/com.homework.personalstuff.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter.bindView(com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter$IFragmentView)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter.bindView(com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter$IFragmentView)' on a null object reference
        at com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfile.onStart(FragmentProfile.java:133)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2287)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1458)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3227)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3186)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2293)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1458)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3227)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3186)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:203)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:582)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at com.homework.personalstuff.ActivityMain.onStart(ActivityMain.java:80)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7019)
```

Comment: please post the code of `FragmentProfilePresenter` and `FragmentProfile`

Comment: You are adding the fragments again, look to your logs, FragmentProfileBase its called twice because you add other fragment to the fragment manager.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from your logs you are implementing MVP architecture so you need to inject an instance of a presenter to your fragment before it is used. If you set presenter manually `onAttachFragment` callback of activity or fragment (depends on where your fragment is hosted) is a good place to do this. If you use dependency injection `onViewCreated` lifecycle callback is suitable to inject.

Comment: You are right. The problem was in nullable presenter while fragment has been restored, so I had to remove creating presenter from `onCreate` to `onActivityCreated` of all fragments. Seems it is works for now.

Comment: But still have a problems with restoring fragments: seems the app creates many instances of fragments on each restoring from background

Comment: If an activity was destroyed by a system when it comes to foreground every its fragment will be restored. However, it shouldn't happen all the time if you have enough free RAM on your device. Maybe you have Don't Keep Activities developer option enabled on your device. Could you please specify the problem in more details?

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter.bindView(com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfilePresenter$IFragmentView)' on a null object reference
        at com.homework.personalstuff.FragmentProfile.onStart(FragmentProfile.java:133)
```

From the above logs, it looks like `FragmentProfile.java` has some issue **at line number 133**, may be a method is getting called with null object reference.

Please do null checks in your code!

Comment: The question is not about this crash